# Случайные числа от 10 до 20

Tags: java

Здрасте, как задать диапазон случайных чисел от 10 до 20 к примеру, думал вот  так но это не правильно

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(10) * 20;
```

Comment: Вы можете сделать ещё вот такую штучку:

`public int genRandom(int min, int max) {

Random r = new Random();

return r.nextInt(max - min) + 1;

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@timedo](/users/15596/timedo)](/users/15596/timedo), поскольку [rand.nextInt(10)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) возвращает числа от нуля до 9 (включительно), то надо не умножать, а складывать.

```
rand.nextInt(11) + 10; // от 10 до 20 (включительно)
```